# Image Data Generator: how can I test the parallelism?

Tags: keras, keras-2

I've created an `ImageDataGenerator` for Keras, and I would like to make sure that it runs in parallel, meaning it generates a batch while Keras processes the previous generated batch. But the parallelism is handled directly by Keras.

Is there simple test to make sure it is well parallelized?